# How do I get the phone number of gumtree when its hidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, web-scraping

The URL I am trying to scrape = https://www.gumtree.com/p/property-to-rent/newly-decorated-3-bed-flat-with-living-room-and-balcony-for-rent/1394143991?srn=true

So far I have tried using selenium to login and check the phone number but that does not work. Logging in just renders a blank page via selenium.

[image: Post Login ScreenShot]

The above screenshot is after clicking on the reveal button via selenium and then logging in using a valid account. The above screenshot is rendered after entering login details and clicking on the log in button.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('pathhere')
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r'patherhere')
#driver = webdriver.Edge('pathhere')
        
driver.get('https://www.gumtree.com/p/property-to-rent/newly-decorated-3-bed-flat-with-living-room-and-balcony-for-rent/1394143991?srn=true')

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Reveal')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)

time.sleep(2)
        
emailInp = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
time.sleep(2)
emailInp.send_keys('email here')
time.sleep(2)
passwordInp = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
time.sleep(2)
passwordInp.send_keys('password here')
time.sleep(2)
submit=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/main/div/section/div/form/fieldset/div[3]/button')
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)
time.sleep(2)
```

As seen in the above code I have used almost all web browsers but they give me the same result :/ Is there any way I can log in to this site? The default login on the home page of the above site also renders a white blank page for me. Is there a different method for getting the hidden-phone number? Thank you for reading. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the window size? like driver.set_window_size(1080,640)

You can also use DriverWait class to wait for the elements you want to interact with to be visible.

**wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
landing_page = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath-value")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(landing_page).perform()**

Comment: All buttons and text boxes work perfectly well. It's just when you log in it is a blank page. The website might know it is a bot and prevent it. I just don't know how.